# Convergence range of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac {(-1)^n3n}{(x-4)^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> Find the range of convergence of $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac {(-1)^n3n}{(x-4)^n}$

Finding the radius first, setting $t=x-4$, $R=1/|((-1)^n3n)^{1/n}|=1$

So $\mid \frac 1 {x-4}\mid<1\to 1<|x-4| \to x>5 \vee x<3 $. But this isn't right, I checked with a convergence calculator and the series converges with any $x$. What is wrong here?

EDIT: I found my mistake, the range is supposed to be: $x>5 \vee x<3$

Comment: Glad to know that you found the mistake !

Comment: Nice............................+1